# Get Documents from Cosmosdb Java Cross partition query is required but disabled

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```
public static Document getDocumentById(String id) {

  FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
     queryOptions.setMaxItemCount(10);
     queryOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);

  // Retrieve the document using the DocumentClient.
  List<Document> documentList = documentClient
        .queryDocuments(getTodoCollection().getSelfLink(),
              "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='" + id + "'",null,queryOptions)
        .getQueryIterable().toList();

  if (documentList.size() > 0) {
     return documentList.get(0);
  } else {
     return null;
  }
```

Hello, I am trying to get some help with retrieving a document from Cosmosdb using Java using the code above.
I am getting the following error:

> WARNING: Operation will NOT be retried. Exception: Cross partition
>   query is required but disabled. Please set
>   x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify
>   x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this
>   exception. ActivityId: 09c62e77-f9dc-4cc7-902d-0cd8c5cad8a6,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0

Any help you can provide me would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched for the `queryDocuments` method overloads from [Document DB Java SDK API Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.queryDocuments?view=azure-java-stable),it seems a little bit different from your sample code. I suppose you set the `FeedOptions` at the wrong order of parameters. Please use below code and it works for me.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;

import java.util.List;

public class QueryDocumentsTest {

    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY="***";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT,
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY,
                new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
//        queryOptions.setMaxItemCount(10);
        queryOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
        String id = "b01cf483-15e0-517c-deae-2e71bafe7d12";

        // Retrieve the document using the DocumentClient.
        List<Document> documentList = client
                .queryDocuments("dbs/db/colls/part",
                        "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='" + id + "'",queryOptions)
                .getQueryIterable().toList();

        if (documentList.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(documentList.get(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("null");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I found out my problem I needed to have my library set to the latest version on maven so that the correct queryoptions were there.